# Scope of tertiary+ functions in XSLT

Tags: xslt, scope, xslt-2.0

`A.xsl` includes `B.xsl` includes `C.xsl`, which contains the definition for function `x:test()`. Is `x:test()` out of scope for templates in `A.xsl`? What should happen if `A.xsl` calls `x:test()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the function x:text() in c.xsl and include or import in b.xsl and a.xsl.
I wrote an example  to demonstrate the point:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:x="http://www.test.com/functions">
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="text" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<!--c.xsl-->
<xsl:function name="x:text">
               <xsl:param name="string"/> <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
</xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>

<xsl:stylesheet>
  <xsl:include href="c.xsl"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="text" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<!--b.xsl-->
  <xsl:variable name="myFunc" select="x:text('b')"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:x="http://www.test.com/functions">
 <xsl:output indent="yes" method="text" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
 <xsl:include href="b.xsl"/>
 <!--a.xsl-->
<xsl:template match="/">
 x:text()  was called in b.xsl:   <xsl:value-of select="$myFunc"/>; 
 x:text()  is called in a.xsl:  <xsl:value-of select="x:text('a')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Do you happen to know where this behavior is defined in the XSLT spec?

Comment: See http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt under 2.6.1 Stylesheet Inclusion
<!-- Category: top-level-element -->
<xsl:include
  href = uri-reference />